# If $A$ is bounded, then $\partial A$ is bounded.

Tags: general-topology

Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^2 $, $A \neq \emptyset$. 
If $A$ is bounded, then $\partial A$ is bounded.?

Comment: The boundary of $A$ is a subset of the closure of $A$. If $A$ is bounded, is its closure bounded?

Answer (score 3):

By definition we have $\partial A\subseteq \bar{A}$. So assume $||x||\leq M$ for all $x\in A$. For every $y\in\partial{A}$ there exists a sequence $(y_n)\subseteq A$ which converges to $y$. This implies $||y_n||\to ||y||$ and hence $||y||\leq M$ as well. So $\partial A$ is indeed bounded.

Answer (score 0):

In every neighbourhood of a boundary point there are points that belong to the set. If the elements of the set are all concentrated in a certain ball centered in $(0,0)$, the points in the boundary cannot be outside the closure of that ball.